# Como recorrer con foreach de atras hacia delante

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

estoy haciendo un blog y me gustaría que se muestren las entradas del blog de la mas nueva a la más antigua, me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de recorrer de atrás hacia adelante con un foreach.

El código que tengo ahora es este:

```
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
<img src="<%= blog.image %>" style="height: 200px">
<p><h4><%= blog.title %></h4><span><%= blog.category %></span></p>
<p><%= blog.content %></p>

<p><%= moment(blog.createdAt).fromNow() %></p>
```

Comment: Hola varox , la forma que se me ocurre es con for no con foreach, ya que puedes poner las variable y definir que empieze de atras para adelante, Pero que estas recorriendo? lo podrias mostrar.

Comment: hola en vez de realizar un foreach invertido, puede poner en la sentecias mysql el siguiente codigo al final  **order by id desc**  
 https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: que es blog? una lista ordenada de objetos? una arreglo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta opción es lenta pero hay que mencionarla.

Tu codigo funcionaria perfecto solo que debes ordenar inversamente tu arreglo con la funcion [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse)

```
    <% blogs.reverse() %>
    <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <img src="<%= blog.image %>" style="height: 200px">
    <p><h4><%= blog.title %></h4><span><%= blog.category %></span></p>
    <p><%= blog.content %></p>

    <p><%= moment(blog.createdAt).fromNow() %></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

En vez de utilizar un `forEach`, utiliza un `for` normal iterando desde el tamaño del array hasta 0.

```
<% for(i = blogs.length; i > 0; i--){ %>
<img src="<%= blogs[i].image %>" style="height: 200px">
<p><h4><%= blogs[i].title %></h4><span><%= blogs[i].category %></span></p>
<p><%= blogs[i].content %></p>

<p><%= moment(blogs[i].createdAt).fromNow() %></p>
```

Comment: Destacar que lo mejor sería que de la BD obtengas los post ordenados por la fecha, de ésa manera no tienes que hacer ésto en la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba dándole la vuelta a el array que le pasas en caso de que sea un array
quizá esto te sirva https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse